# Hibernate IS NOT throwing StaleObjectStateException (DO NOT DO OPTIMISTIC LOCKING)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am puzzled here. I wanted to implement optimistic locking in my spring hibernate program but the hibernate is not throwing StaleObjectStateException even though I open a data in separate browser and updated it separately.

My Dao looks like this:

```
public void update(User user) throws StaleObjectStateException{       
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

My Pojo look like this:

```
@Version@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="timestamp", length=19)
public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
return this.timestamp;
}
```

Config.xml

```
<bean name="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean name="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

One of my doubt why it is NOT throwing exception is that upon update, the other session timestamp is also updated since the data is persisted? Please help.

Perry

Comment: guys anyone knows about my problem?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are persisting the User (via form submit)?

Comment: is there some kind of client-server architecture? Do you use DTOs? Are the entities directly sent to the client? How does the transaction look like where you update the user? (loading user from database, copying values? Or just putting serialized entity into database?)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using spring transaction manager. So I suppose somewhere you have `@Transactional` annotation that tracks your transactions. In this case I think that `StaleObjectStateException`will be thrown not on execution of update method of you class but when the transaction will be commited. And I also think that spring will wrap hibernate exception into `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`. So you need to add throws declaration to the method that marked with `@Transactional` annotation.
If you do not have any transactional annotation than you need to add some or use manual transaction handling in Dao.